# Stop timed function in AngularJS 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little test I'm working on while learning Angular JS 1.  I have some text areas which display some text via an Angular function when the user enters and exits them. The enter function waits 3 seconds and the exit function waits 5 seconds.  This is working so far.

The next part of the task is to cancel the functions from binding the text to the text area if the user does not wait the amount of the timeouts.  I'm stumped on that one but I think I need to use promises.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function checkTimeout() {
  console.log("Timeout is working...");
}

myApp.filter('rawHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
   return function(val) {
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
}])

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $timeout){

$timeout(checkTimeout, 3000);

$scope.data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "act": ""
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "act": ""
}];

$scope.enter1 = function(num) {
  $timeout (function(){num.act = " - enter";}, 3000 );
}

$scope.exit1 = function(num) {
  $timeout (function(){num.act = " - exit";}, 5000 );
}


})
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="width:100%;margin:10px;">
      <p>How can I stop the functions enter1 and exit1 from binding text to the textarea if the user does not wait the 3 seconds (enter1) and 5 seconds (exit1) for them to execute?</p>
      <div style="float:right; width:49%;">
        <div ng-repeat="num in data" style="margin:3px;">
          <textarea ng-focus="enter1(num)" ng-blur="exit1(num)">{{ num.id }}{{ num.act }}</textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mediaguru/q3qt5frk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) constructor returns a value, which can be used to access the timer.

```
var myTimer = $timeout(checkTimeout, 3000);

//Kill it
$timeout.cancel (myTimer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dominic. So in your example how would I tie in the blur with the $timeout.cancel, if it happened within the 3000ms?  Hope that's not too unclear.

Comment: Basically, whenever you start a timer, store it in a variable. If you need to end the timer prematurely, call $timeout.cancel on the variable. Otherwise just let it run and ignore it. I'd add more context, but I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: Let's just take the focus function.  The user tabs or clicks into the field. If the user stays in the field for 3 seconds or more, the word "enter" appears in the field.  If the user were to leave that field before 3 seconds, the word enter would NOT appear.

Comment: So yes, in the blur function cancel the timer that you set in the focus function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear all the timers. Otherwise, memory leaks will be there. Clear timer if the element that invokes the timer is destroyed. In angular, every element have scope. And `$scope.$destroy()` will trigger if the scope of a specific element destroyed where we have to clear all timers and events.

```
var timers = new Array();
...
// add a timer to the array
timers.push(setTimeout('someFunc()', 1000));
...
// clear all timers in the array
for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++)
{
    clearTimeout(timers[i]);
}
```